# stderr output missing from CalledProcessError in check_output

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I have the following block of code in a Python 3 function

```py
try:
  score_string = subprocess.check_output([sys.executable, "-m", "query",
                                          lab,
                                          data_frame_path,
                                          prior_model_path,
                                          channel], stderr=subprocess.PIPE).decode('utf-8')
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
  out_bytes = e.output       # Output generated before error
  err_bytes = e.stderr
  code = e.returncode   # Return code
  if log:
      log.error("Invocation of train_model on %s %s %s failed with error %d." %
                (lab, data_frame_path, prior_model_path, code))
      log.error("Error output is:")
      log.error(out_bytes.decode('utf-8'))
      if err_bytes is not None:
          log.error(err_bytes.decode('utf-8'))
      return None
return eval(score_string)
```

When it encounters an error in the subprocess, though, it does not print any of the output that when to `stderr`.  All I see is:

```
2019-02-18 17:29:18 ERROR    Invocation of train_model on Transcriptic ../data/pipeline/experiment.r1bbm2c4eyvsp_amazed-sponge_mefl_hist\
.csv ../data/trained/pipeline_mefl_hist/ failed with error 1.
2019-02-18 17:29:18 ERROR    Error output is:
2019-02-18 17:29:18 ERROR
```

I suspect that there's some problem with how I invoke `check_output`, and particularly the `stderr` argument.  I have read the documentation, but failed to understand it.  I believe I must do *something* to capture `stderr` so that it gets inserted into the `CalledProcessError`, but I don't know what is right to do.

Comment: "I believe I must do something to capture `stderr` so that it gets inserted into the `CalledProcessError`"

You already do capture `stderr` when you set it to be `subprocess.PIPE` when invoking `subprocess.check_output`.

The error from running the command is captured and available in the `stderr` attribute of the `subprocess.CalledProcessError` instance. Are you getting any error traceback when you invoke the train model directly in the shell. I'd check that an error is throw in the training script

Comment: @OluwafemiSule Maybe I wasn't clear about what's going on in the example.  I am printing the `stderr` attribute of the exception, but nothing is in it.  Somehow the error message is being lost.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule I think you are right, after all. I had a separate error that seems to have caused the loss of error output, and now it appears to work properly.

Comment: Glad that you figured it out! 